# Set a value to a variable in accordance with another

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop

I want to set the value 6 to the variable "M3_rankin_factor" when "M3_mortalite" variable is equal to 1.

```
  summary(M2clean$M3_rankin_factor)  
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6 NA's
 176   71   44   31   52   29    3   71 


  summary(M2clean$M3_mortalite)
Non  Oui NA's 
402   34   41 


  for (i in rownames(M2clean)) {if(!is.na(M2clean$M3_mortalite[i]) && M2clean$M3_mortalite == 1) M2clean$M3_rankin_factor[i] <- 6}


  summary(M2clean$M3_rankin_factor)
   0    1    2    3    4    5    6 NA's 
 176   71   44   31   52   29    3   71
```

I don't understand

Comment: Thank you very much, but it doesn't work. I want to keep the 6 classes and this formule recode into 2 classes :

summary(M2clean$M3_rankin_factor)

   1    2 NA's 

 402   34   41

Comment: Can you post result of `dput(M2clean)`? and see [reproducible-example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: It's a big database: I can extract the whole text from the console and paste here... I read the reproducible-example, thank you.

Comment: How about `str(M2clean)` or `dput(head(M2clean))`, so we know more about the data...

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
M2clean$M3_rankin_factor[M2clean$M3_mortalite == 1] <- 6
```

Comment: `M3_rankin_factor` is a factor so this won't work. See comment from the OP.

Comment: How about converting it to character first `M2clean$M3_rankin_factor <- as.character(M2clean$M3_rankin_factor)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
M2clean$M3_rankin_factor[which(M2clean$M3_mortalite==1)] <- 6
```

as long as 1 and 6 are valid factor levels for the variables involved.
Using `which` instead of `M2clean$M3_mortalite==1` you avoid the NA problem.
I've tested it: it works on factor too

```
f <- as.factor(c(NA,1,2,3))
#[1] <NA> 1    2    3
f[which(f==1)] <- 3
#[1] <NA> 3    2    3
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, it works. 
An another answer :

```
M2clean[M2clean$M3_mortalite == "Oui" & (!is.na(M2clean$M3_mortalite)), "M3_rankin_factor"] <- 6
```